# Eloquent: Distinct values and counts from relations

Tags: eloquent

I have a DB structure as follows:

```
 fashion_item
==============
| id | name  |
|------------|
| 1  | item1 |
|------------|
| 2  | item2 |
--------------

 fashion_colour
===============
| id | name   |
|-------------|
| 1  | red    |
|-------------|
| 2  | white  |
|-------------|
| 3  | green  |
---------------
| 4  | black  |
---------------

 fashion_color_fashion_item
======================================
| fashion_item_id | fashion_color_id |
|------------------------------------|
| 1               | 1                |
|------------------------------------|
| 1               | 2                |
|------------------------------------|
| 1               | 3                |
|------------------------------------|
| 2               | 2                |
|------------------------------------|
| 2               | 3                |
--------------------------------------
```

The `fashion_color_fashion_item` table is a join table for a many to many relationship between `fashion_item` and `fashion_color`.

Using Eloquent, I would like to retrieve a list of results from fashion_item (based on other criteria) then get a distinct list of `fashion_colour` id's from the results, with a count.

I need to end up with a value like the following, though I'm willing to transform the relevant data from another structure.

```
[ 1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 2, 4 => 0 ]
```

In this format, there is a key which reflects a `fashion_color.id`, and a value which represents the number of times the colour is referenced by a row from the result set.

`fashion_colour.id`'s with no count result can be null, 0 or simply not present.

I have the correct relationships setup between the tables and I can return results using all of the regular methods, including eager loading the colour data.

---

I've been able to achieve a similar result on direct belongs to relationships by grouping the results based on the foreign key in the table and counting the array. This won't work for many-to-many relationships.

e.g.

```
$silhouetteFilterList = array();
$results = FashionItem::(where clauses, etc...)->get();

$silhouettes = $results->groupBy('fashion_silhouette_id')->all();
foreach ($silhouettes as $key => $value) {
    $silhouetteFilterList[$key] = count($value);
}
```

P.S. We're currently using Eloquent 4.1 because we need PHP 5.3 compatibility, we're hoping to move on soon. Comments regarding the antiquated nature of either PHP5.3 or Eloquent 4.1 will not be welcome :p

We are using Eloquent but not Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Try eager loading the relationship:

```
$collection = $items->with('colors')->get();
```

Each item in the collection should now have a `colors` variable that represents an array of colors for that particular item.

Since this is a general Laravel Collection, you can use collection and array methods to get it in the format you like.